# How to stop solution deployment

Tags: solution-deployment

I started some solutions deployment with batch file and one of them was hanging. So I stopped the script and tried to retract that one solution to deploy it once again

```
stsadm -o retractsolution -name solutionname.wsp -immediate -allcontenturls
```

This gives me error message:

> A deployment or retraction is already under way for the solution "solutionname.wsp", and only one deployment or retraction at a time is supported.

I tried to stop it with `iisreset` and by going to Services and restarting `SharePoint 2010 Timer` service. That didn't help.

How to stop previous solution deployment, so I can try again?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a `stsadm -o canceldeployment -id <id>`

To get the ID you have to use `stsadm -o enumdeployments`

Just be sure that your *Timer Job* is running.

Comment: `stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs` to process current deployments could also help.

Answer (score 5):

Paul Liebrand posted a [blog post](http://www.paulliebrand.com/2014/05/13/powershell-to-cancel-all-sharepoint-%20solution-deployments/) which would do the magic in PowerShell.

I assume you could modify the *where/?* part to fit your needs, like matching the solution id for example.

```
Get-SPTimerJob | ? {$_.Name -like "Solution-Deployment*" } | % { $_.Delete() }
```

I haven't got a chance to try this myself.